# I am getting issue of file.buffer and file.originalname as undefined

Tags: typescript, nestjs

[This is media.controller.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaXWw.jpg)

[This is media.service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY4as.jpg)

image gets uploaded as undefined
file.buffer and file.originalname shows undefined
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruun4.png)

Thanks in advance, please help me out of this

Comment: Please edit to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

As i know file from controller is an array of objects,please try to pass to service 0th item of file

Comment: I did that, i am passing file[0].buffer now, but it throws error when sending request

Comment: This Error, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buffer')"

Comment: I did console.log(file) also it prints........ [AsyncFunction: getMultipartFile]